# prime ng: Identify which p-splitter-gutter-handle was moved inside p-splitter

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I need to to identify the p-splitter-gutter-handle moved inside a nested template.

I prepared a stackblitz with an example of what I mean by nested. That is, multiple handlers in a single <p-splitter and I would like to understand in real time which handler has been moved

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-splitter-demo-3o6ewv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onResizeStart` or `onResizeEnd` event of the `p-splitter`. Place one one each of the `p-splitter` elements you have and pass an id to the handler, like this:

```
<p-splitter [panelSizes]="[20, 80]" (onResizeEnd)="resizeEndHandler(1)">
    <ng-template pTemplate>
        <div>Panel 1</div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate>
        <p-splitter layout="vertical" [panelSizes]="[15, 85]" (onResizeEnd)="resizeEndHandler(2)">
            <ng-template pTemplate>
                <div>Panel 2</div>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate>
                <div>Panel 3</div>
            </ng-template>
        </p-splitter>
    </ng-template>
</p-splitter>
```

In your component code:

```
public resizeEndHandler(splitterID) {
    console.log("Splitter moved", splitterID);

    // Do something
}
```